# Return uncommitted changes after "git checkout"

Tags: git, git-checkout

I had some changes on master and then I created a branch where I added all my changes. Then, I went back to master to remove the changes that I did. I entered `git checkout .` which unstaged all of my changes on master and the branch.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you did `git pull --rebase` after `git checkout` ?

Comment: I have many ideas - yesterday I thought of a machine that (un)shells pumpkin seeds, and the day before that I had a good idea of how my bike's suspension got damaged. Why do you ask?

Comment: @Karam what are you exactly asking? To "revert" the `git checkout .` command?

Comment: yep @double-beep

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, you **can't** "revert" the `git checkout .` command you entered. Your changes are gone, sorry :(.

Please check [git-undoing-things](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things) for more information.